# 32 bit application crashing in 64 bit OS due to higher memory consumption

Tags: memory, memory-management, 64-bit, wow64

I have a 32 bit version of a .net application running in two different machines .
One is 32 bit machine and the other is 64 bit machine.

In the 64 bit environment the 32 bit application runs in WoW64 environment.

The 64 bit machine configuration is 4GB RAM.

But the same application with the same workflow is consuming 500MB in 32 bit OS while it is taking more than 1GB in 64 bit OS and crashes.

I read the following articles related to this.

http://blogs.sepago.de/helge/2008/03/11/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-5

http://blogs.citrix.com/2011/10/13/wow64-memory-mapping-of-32bit-apps-running-on-a-64bit-windows/

But their analysis is not deterministic. Had any one of you faced this issue? Are there any recommendations for a 32 bit app to run in 64 bit environment?

Comment: Why is it taking so much memory in the first place?

Comment: You need to create a **lot** of kernel-level data structures to get a 500 MB difference between the two. I can't imagine how this is sensibly possible...

Comment: @nneonneo: It is a .Net application bundled with frequent SQL access. That workflow is quite complex with thousands of SQL calls and hence it is consuming 500MB in 32 bit environment.

Comment: 1000 *sequential* SQL calls shouldn't amount to much unless you're pushing some seriously big datasets around. Have you checked the project references? Try making a blank project with dummy calls into every one of your current references and see if the memory usage goes crazy.

Comment: @nneonneo: It is not about it is consuming more memory. My worry here is why is there a large difference between 64 bit OS and 32 bit OS memory usage

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm just trying to figure out where your base of 500MB comes from. AFAIK, you *might* be experiencing bloat due to 64-bit referenced assemblies vs. 32-bit referenced assemblies, but 500MB of bloat is rather obscene.

Answer (score 1):

The differences in 64 Bit mode are:

- 64 bit call stacks instead of 32 bit call stacks. Additionally have the WOW64 call stack
- 64 bit datatypes used instead of 32 bit datatypes
- 64 bit DLLs loaded instead of 32 bit DLLs

500 MB only in call stacks is unlikely. A stack has typically 1 MB reserved but only 64 kB committed.

Datatypes might be an issue, especially if you have a .NET application compiled for AnyCPU. Are you sure you compiled a pure 32 bit application?

DLLs can make a huge difference. Especially some SQL DLLs have 130 MB size, so loading the 64 Bit version can make a huge difference. It still does not explain doubled memory usage and again, applies only for AnyCPU .NET apps.

Next question is: why does the application crash at 1 GB already and not somewhere close to 2 GB (32 Bit) or 4 GB (AnyCPU) on a 64 bit operating system? Are you sure you have measured the correct thing? Maybe you measured private bytes only or even working set size, which would both not really help here.